# App Inventor cannot connect to phone or emulator

Tags: android, emulation, app-inventor

I've created a screen with a lot of pictures (75 pictures), which are not visible. Since I've added the last 50 pictures, the Blocks Editor cannot connect to the phone or emulator anymore. I really need all of the pictures for my app. Is it possible, that 75 pictures in one Screen are too much?

I also can't download the app to my computer at the moment, because the build server is currently busy :-/

Answer (score 0):

How large are your pictures?
Are you aware, that there is a 5 MB limit for App Inventor apps?

There are the following workarounds
1. [Hossein's solution](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/apptomarket/QpKUWld912g/discussion) 
2. [Shival Wolf's webprefetch](http://ai.kittywolf.net/index.php/Webprefetch) or [Taifun's webprefetch file by file](http://puravidaapps.com/filebyfile.php)
3. [Gary's solution](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/usgsuacwai/9uHYHr2AU_8/discussion)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that...the folder, the pictures are in, is 2,29 MB.

Comment: this should be no problem... try restarting your computer, this often helps ;-) and alternatively test on a device instead of the emulator to see if that works... also see the [troubleshooting tips](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/troubleshooting)

Comment: didn't help...I've downloaded the apk to my computer and installed it on the phone. But everytime I want to go to screen with the 75 pictures the app crashes.

I've splitted my 75 pictures on 3 screens now with 25 pictures each. this works...